# Expose API using other server and SSH tunnel

Tags: python, api, ssh, jupyter, tunnel

I have been trying to solve this for a couple of days and don't seem to find a way to do it. I have a raspberry pi in my local network which is running jupyter (port 8888) and a flask api (port 5000). I want to be able to access it remotely using another server. My setup and what I have until now is:

Server in GCP with static IP (let's say it's gcp.static.ip). I opened the ports 7003 and 7004 as udp.

Raspberry Pi in my home network with dynamic IP (can't have static IP) and jupyter and flask api on ports 8888 and 5000. I forwarded the ports with:

```
ssh -NR 7003:localhost:5000 -R 7004:localhost:88888 user@gcp.static.ip
```

Laptop in remote network. If I do the following ssh tunnel I can access the jupyter server at localhost:7004:

```
ssh -NL 7004:localhost:7004 user@gcp.static.ip
```

I can't seem to do the same for the flask API. If I ssh into the gcp server I can query the API at port 7003. How can I set the gcp server so that I can query the api with gcp.static.ip:APIPort and access jupyter in gcp.static.ip:JupyterPort.

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: I'm able to query the api forwarding a TCP port. However, still want to know if this is possible without having to create another tunnel on my lapto.

Comment: unless you've taken extra steps, Flask may require TCP

Comment: Makes sense, so should I open port 7003 as TCP?

Answer (score 1):

Following this [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/517143/how-to-tunnel-a-local-port-onto-a-remote-server). Had to change /etc/ssh/sshd_config to set GatewayPorts to clientspecified and ssh tunnel with:

```
ssh -NR 0.0.0.0:7003:localhost:5000 user@gcp.static.ip
```